# Java: Thread joins over 10,000 iterations inconsistent

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Alright folks.. I'm back again (seems to be my home lately).

I'm going through the whole cave of programming YouTube vids on multi-threading.  This particular one uses 2 threads that go through a for loop which adds 1 to a variable 10,000 times each.  So you join them so the result is 20,000 when it's done.

```
public class main {

private int count = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   main main = new main();
   main.doWork();
}

public void doWork(){

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                count++;
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                count++;
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Thing is.. when i change the iterations:

i < 10 = 20 (correct)

i < 100 = 200 (correct)

i < 1000 = 2000 (correct)

i < 10000 = 13034 (first run)

= 14516 (second run)

= ... etc..

Why won't it properly handle iterations in the tens of thousands?

Comment: The answer is obvious: You have shared mutable data that isn't synchronized.

Comment: Oh my gosh... I need to go to sleep... that was a horrible question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have demonstrated the classic race condition, which occurs when 2 or more threads are reading and writing to the same variable in conflicting ways.  This arises because the `++` operator isn't an atomic operation -- multiple operations are occurring, and a thread could be interrupted in between operations, e.g.:

1. Thread `t1` reads `count` (`0`), and calculates the incremented value (`1`), but it hasn't stored the value back to `count` yet.
2. Thread `t2` reads `count` (still `0`), and calculates the incremented value (`1`), but it hasn't stored the value back to `count` yet.
3. Thread `t1` stores its `1` value back to `count`.
4. Thread `t2` stores its `1` value back to `count`.

Two updates have occurred, but the net result is only an increase of `1`.  The set of operations which must not be interrupted is a *critical section*.

This appears to have happened 20,000 - 13,034 times, or 6,966 times in your first execution.  You may have gotten lucky with lower bounds, but regardless of the magnitude of the bounds, the race condition can happen.

In Java, there are several solutions:

1. Place [`synchronized` blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) around the critical sections (both `count++` lines), locking on `this`.
2. Change `count` to an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which encapsulates such operations atomically on its own.  The `getAndIncrement` method would replace the `++` operator here.